# WordPress how to use escaping function for numbers and object, e.g. post_type

Tags: wordpress, escaping

PHPCS is showing

> "All outputs should be run through an escaping function..."

The following two lines of code are responsible for the above message:

`<?php echo $counter; ?>`
and
`<div class="four columns <?php echo $post_type; ?>" data-sr >...</div>`

What are the right ways to escape a number and an object in WordPress?

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: weird - But i guess you could wrap your outputs in `echo esc_html($whatever);`

Comment: I can. But isn't there any specific function for number or object types. Question is when we are dealing with a number, why should we use `esc_html`? Also I feel this is not right for `PHPCS` to return an error when outputting a pure number. As long as post_type name is concerned, yes, we can use `esc_html()` function on it.

Comment: since echo is a language construct, it will turn it into a string - PHP is fluid, if you can echo it, it is read as a string. right?

Answer (score 0):

> What are the right ways to escape a number and an object in WordPress?

Escaping is not so much about the content being escaped, but about the *context* it is being escaped for. That's one reason why late escaping is recommended, because the same data may be escaped for multiple contexts.

Consider the expansion of the function names - escaping for HTML, escaping for JavaScript, escaping for attributes, escaping for URL attributes, escaping for textarea. In the loosely-typed environment, none of those strictly care whether the thing being escaped contains a string, a bool or an integer (it treats them all as a string).

However, there are other ways to escape, which you may find more preferable. In this case, the following would also be sufficient:

`<?php echo (int) $counter; ?>`
and
`<div class="four columns <?php echo sanitize_html_class( $post_type ); ?>" data-sr >...</div>`

Reference:

- [Casts values](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/blob/0b38e78301729e060eed91ed83e4c3d940e877c1/WordPress/Sniffs/Security/EscapeOutputSniff.php#L146) and [usage](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/blob/0b38e78301729e060eed91ed83e4c3d940e877c1/WordPress/Sniffs/Security/EscapeOutputSniff.php#L412-L416)
- [WP Functions considered to
  escape](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/blob/0b38e78301729e060eed91ed83e4c3d940e877c1/WordPress/Sniff.php#L154), including `sanitize_html_class()`.